# Apple Push Notification Service on user response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to track user response (the choice between the 'View' and 'Close') when the message has been push into the user device?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is not notified if the user clicks "Close"; but if the user clicks "View", your app is launched, and you can detect that it was launched from a notification -- the notification's payload is passed to [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a).

Also, don't forget about the case where your app might already be running when the notification comes in.  In that case, your [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveRemoteNotification%3a) function will be called.

Full details are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).

Answer (score 0):

My strategy would be:

1. Keep a record of the user's device token when your server fires a APNs notification.
2. Implement the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** and **didReceiveRemoteNotification** methods accordingly, so that whenever the user's device becomes active due to your APNs notification, it sends a request to let your server know. This request should contain the device token.
3. Your server does a look-up and match process, once such a request is received.