# Track user response in C2DM

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

I am doing push notification for android using C2DM. it works well. but while receiving message in mobile, user can only view the message.

if we took APNS for iphone as example, user can response to the notification by clicking "view" button or "close" button. by using this i can track the response.
[Apple Push Notification Service on user response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655053/apple-push-notification-service-on-user-response)

is it possible to do this in android C2DM?
i want to track the user response for the notification like apns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive your message on your `Receiver` you can implement to start a new activity whcih looks like a dialog having a View and a Dismiss button and have some cutom functionality in the `onClickListeners` for each button.

Let me explain, in your `IntentService` there must be a method which receives the response from C2DM that is `onMessage` and this has the params `Context` and `Intent` and you can use the `Context` variable to start a new activity(or a `AlertDialog`) which has a theme dialog and has the two buttons and do what I said in the above para.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply.actually i am not a mobile developer. i am creating a web app to send message to android and want to track the user response in my web app. one more doubt. is it possible to send any custom values while calling c2dm from my web app? (just like any message identifier)